# looping through multiple file upload indexes

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to get the name and size index of all uploaded files but I can't get it work. it works like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $file){
         echo $file;

         }
```

but if I want to echo multiple indexes in the same loop, i tries this, but I get "undefined index 'name' and 'size'" warnings. What am I doing wrong? thanks

```
foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $key => $file){
         echo $file['name'].
              $file['size'];

}
    <input name ="file[]" type = "file"  multiple />
```

Comment: May we know how your input form looks like?

Comment: yes one moment please...

Answer (score 1):

```
function handle_image_upload($frmFilesID = false, $thisFile = false) {
        $tmpName = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['tmp_name'][$thisFile];
        if (!is_uploaded_file($tmpName)) { return false; }
        $fileName = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['name'][$thisFile];
        $fileSize = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['size'][$thisFile];
        $fileType = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['type'][$thisFile];
            ...
```